# How to show a picture box inside a panel on hover programmatically?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following problem, because I am quite new I don't know if I am asking the right questions...Hope someone can put me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

I have a panel. Inside it there is a textbox(same size as the panel(140*40) and a pictureBox(smaller and in the right top corner, 15*15).At the moment I am able when I `MouseHover` the panel(and the textbox) to show a pictureBox with an image with a deleting in it. But if I pass the mouse over the picturebox himself it dissapears, and I want that this happens only when I `MouseLeave` the textbox or the panel.

A college told me that I must use the parent property, but I have no idea how can I do that.

I don't know if my explanation is any good, but I leave you some code here, so you can point me to the solution.

`Textbox` is `tbRole`, `Panel` is `pnRole` and `PictureBox` is `pbDeleteX`:

```
tbRole.MouseMove += (senderL, eL) =>
        {
            if (mouseHover)
            {
                pbDeleteX.Visible = true;
                mouseHover = true;
            }
            else
            {
                pbDeleteX.Visible = true;
                mouseHover = false;
            }      
            tbRole.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            pnRole.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
            // Je dois mettre ici le DoDragDrop parce que sinon sa ne marche pas le doubleclick
            if (eL.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                idRoleG = idRoleL;
                tbRole.BringToFront();
                clRol = tbRole.BackColor;
                mouseDown = true;
                tbRole.AllowDrop = true;

                tbRole.DoDragDrop(tbRole, DragDropEffects.Move);
            }

        };            
        tbRole.MouseHover += (senderL, eL) =>
        {
            if (mouseHover)
            {
                pbDeleteX.Visible = true;
                mouseHover = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pbDeleteX.Visible = false;
                mouseHover = false;
            }
            tbRole.BackColor = pnRole.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        };            
        tbRole.MouseLeave += (senderL, eL) =>
        {
            pnRole.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
            tbRole.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
            if (mouseHover)
            {
                pbDeleteX.Visible = true;
                mouseHover = false;
            }
            else
            {
                pbDeleteX.Visible = false;
                mouseHover = true;

            }

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this happens because when you hover your mouse cursor over the `pictureBox`, `tbRole.MouseLeave` is fired. You can check it using a breakpoint and see if it happens actually. What you can do is to code 2 boolean variablesFor instance you can say:

```
tbRole.MouseLeave += (senderL, eL) =>
     {
        boolText == false;

        if(boolText == false && boolPic == false) {
            pnRole.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
            tbRole.BackColor = Color.Bisque;
            pbDeleteX.Visible = false;
        }
     };
```

This is what happens:

1. Hover the cursor over the textBox. `boolText == true` and `boolPic == false`
2. Hover the cursor over the pic. `boolText == false` and `boolPic == true`. MouseLeave not fired
3. Leave the picbox. `boolText == true` and `boolPic == false`
4. Leave the textBox. `boolText == false` and `boolText == false`. MouseLeave finally fires and the picBox disappears.

So, you have to add the code of MouseHover and MouseLeave of the `pictureBox` and say that a global variable `boolPic == true` if MouseHover is fired and `boolPic == false` when MouseLeave is fired. Add the same logic in your MouseHover and MouseLeave of the textbox. Then I hope it should work. :P

Comment: Thank you @Emi987 with your answer i tried the boolean and it is working fine, the only thing is that when i move the mouse over the panel(with the textbox and picturebox) very quickly some panel do not show off the picturebox. I change the code the way it is know so you can see if i got an error.

Comment: I'm happy it helped you! :) Anyway, as far as I can see I don't get why you change mouseHover in the MouseMove event. This can bring you in some unexpected behaviour. Suppose it is false. When you moving your mouse over the textBox, mouseHover becomes true. Now, when you fire the mouseHover event, it changes its state from true to false and it should not be because, when you hovering, it must be true. It can happen backwards with your MouseLeave Event.

Comment: You don't need, to summarize, that if-else because they can lead to unexpected behaviours. So, in MuoseLeave, you will code only mouseHover false and in MouseHover only mouseHover true. In MouseMove you should not change the value of mouseHover indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter who is parent, form or panel, so you could simply tell us: textbox (tb) and picturebox (pb).

Next, you have to know, what each control is in fact a *window* (resource with handle). And when you move mouse *into any window* you will get `MouseEnter` event for this window right after `MouseLeave` event for any *previous window* (if any).

This is called WinAPI and windorms follows its rules.

Now, you want following:

- when mouse enters tb, show pb;
- when mouse leaves tb, hide pb (unless its pb).

I don't know why do you use `MouseHover` (which is designated to show tooltips) or `MouseMove` (which is used for many things, but usually with *mouse capturing* or utilizing `MouseLeave` cleanup).

I don't know the best approach, but you can:

### 1) Use mouse capture.

On `MouseEnter` capture the mouse, show pb. During `MouseMove` check when you are out of tb bounds, if you are - release mouse, hide pb.

Because your pb is inside tb bounds this will works as it is.

### 2) Delay pb hiding.

On `MouseEnter` show pb. On `MouseLeave` start timer. On timer tick (0.5 sec later?) stop timer and hide pb. PB also has to have `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`. In pb `MouseEnter` you stop timer. In pb `MouseLeave` you hid pb.

Comment: Thank you @Sinatr with your answer i can understand better.